# OTP verification in node.js backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt, email-verification

The below code is my OTP generation and sending email code. It is working fine.

```
const sendOTPVerification = async ({ _id, email }, res) => {
  console.log(_id, email);
  try {
    const otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
    console.log(otp);
    console.log(process.env.AUTH_EMAIL);

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.AUTH_EMAIL,
      to: email,
      subject: "OTP for Email Verification",
      html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Email Verification</title>
          <style>
              body {
                  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                  background-color: #f4f4f4;
                  padding: 20px;
              }
              .container {
                  max-width: 600px;
                  margin: 0 auto;
                  background-color: #ffffff;
                  padding: 20px;
                  border-radius: 5px;
                  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
              }
              h1 {
                  color: #333;
              }
              p {
                  font-size: 16px;
                  line-height: 1.5;
                  color: #666;
              }
              .otp {
                  font-size: 24px;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  color: #007bff;
              }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="container">
              <h1>Email Verification</h1>
              <p>Thank you for signing up. To complete your registration, please enter the OTP below:</p>
              <p>Your OTP for Email Verification is: <span class="otp">${otp}</span></p>
              <p>If you did not request this OTP, please ignore this email.</p>
          </div>
      </body>
      </html>
      `,
    };

    const saltRounds = 10;
    const hashOTP = await bcrypt.hash(toString(otp), saltRounds);
    const newOTPVerfication = new PublisherOTPVerification({
      publisherId: _id,
      otp: hashOTP,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      expiresAt: Date.now() + 5 * 60 * 1000,
    });

    await newOTPVerfication.save();
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    res.json({
      status: "Pending",
      message: "OTP is sent successfully.",
      data: {
        publisherId: _id,
        email,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: "OTP is not sent.",
      error: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

But when I am trying to verify that using the below code. It gives the error as "error": "Invalid code passed. Check your inbox and try again.". If I remove the bcrypt and save the pure OTP and verify it. It is working. I think that problem is in that bcrypt. Can anyone suggest me to method to correct this error.

```
const verifyOTP = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { publisherId, otp } = req.body;
    if (!publisherId || !otp) {
      throw new Error("Invalid OTP");
    } else {
      const PublisherOTPVerificationRecords =
        await PublisherOTPVerification.find({ publisherId });
      console.log(PublisherOTPVerificationRecords.length);
      if (PublisherOTPVerificationRecords.length <= 0) {
        throw new Error(
          "Account record does not exist or has been verified already. Please sign up or login to continue."
        );
      } else {
        const { expiresAt } = PublisherOTPVerificationRecords[0];
        const hashOTP = PublisherOTPVerificationRecords[0].otp;
        console.log(hashOTP);

        if (expiresAt < Date.now()) {
          await PublisherOTPVerification.deleteMany({ publisherId });
          throw new Error("OTP has expired. Please sign up again.");
        } else {
          const validOTP=await bcrypt.compare(otp,hashOTP);

            if(!validOTP){
              throw new Error("Invalid code passed.Check your inbox and try again.");
          }else{
          await Publisher.updateOne({ _id: publisherId }, { verified: true });
          await PublisherOTPVerification.deleteMany({ publisherId });
          res.json({
            status: "Varified",
            message: "OTP is verified successfully.",
          });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: "OTP is not verified.",
      error: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I found the error in that code. ```const validOTP=await bcrypt.compare(toString(otp),hashOTP);``` second bcrypt should be like this